# The module `EvilIcons` could not be found within the package

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used `"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0"` and import it as 
`import EvilIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'`. But getting bundling failed with error as below.

`` error: bundling failed: Error: While resolving module `react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons`, the Haste package `react-native-vector-icons` was found. However the module `EvilIcons` could not be found within the package. Indeed, none of these files exist:
.....crm/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/EvilIcons(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)` ``

Do you have experience to solve this kind of issue, please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**That's a react-native issue**, see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17610

Will be fixed by https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17672

**Workaround** available at https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/626#issuecomment-362386341